# What does it mean for a set to have an exponent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, boolean-algebra

While learning about boolean algebra I came across this expression: $\{ 0,1 \}^n$. Given the context I understand that this is a set containing the values $0$ and $1$, but what the exponent here means is less clear, which leads me to my question: What does the exponent signify when the base is a set?

Comment: In set theory $A^B$ is the set of function from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: I would expect this to refer to binary strings of length $n$, e.g., $\{0,1\}^3 = \{000,001,010,\ldots,111\}$.

Comment: It means a set of functions from $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ into $\{0, 1\}$. In other words, binary $n$-vectors.

Comment: Another way to think about it is as a repeated Cartesian product of (identical) sets, so that would give a set of $n$-tuples, in this case having combined $2^n$ distinct "points" in the Cartesian product ($2$ times itself, $n$-times).  So the exponent notation is *felicitous*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically $X^A$ denotes the set of all functions $A\to X$.

Now when $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $X^n$ can be defined as $X^{\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$.

Alternatively $X^n$ can be defined as the Cartesian product $X\times\cdots\times X$ of $n$ copies of $X$.

So in your case, for example $\{0,1\}^3$ will be the following set

$$\{(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1),$$
$$(1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)\}$$